# is there any way to search for training metadata in Bixby Studio?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I can find all the places where the value string searchtheme occurs in my trainings by doing this:

```
grep -ir "searchtheme" *
t-1.training.bxb:  utterance ("[g:GetContent] Show me more on the theme of (paintings)[v:SearchTheme].")
t-4.training.bxb:  utterance ("[g:GetContent] Tell me about (when)[v:SearchTheme] Stonehenge was built.")
t-a.training.bxb:  utterance ("[g:GetContent] Show me more on the theme of (music)[v:SearchTheme].")
t-d.training.bxb:  utterance ("[g:GetContent] Show me the (video introduction)[v:SearchTheme].")
t-h.training.bxb:  utterance ("[g:GetContent] Tell me more about (literature)[v:SearchTheme].")
t-o.training.bxb:  utterance ("[g:GetContent] Show me the (video introduction)[v:SearchTheme].")
t-p.training.bxb:  utterance ("[g:GetContent] Tell me about (tourism)[v:SearchTheme].")
t-v.training.bxb:  utterance ("[g:GetContent] Show me the (video introduction)[v:SearchTheme].")
```

but I don't see a way to do that in Bixby Studio itself. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Bixby allows you to search the metadata using their Aligned NL syntax

[More information about searching your NL training](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/training.intro-training#searching-through-training)

[image: Aligned NL]
[image: Example]